# TexLive and Kile

Tags: 12.10, synaptic, latex, kile

I recently had upgraded my machine from a 12.04 installation to a 12.10 version. I use LaTeX for my publication work and therefore I use TexLive and Kile, both of which are on the Ubuntu Package list.

On my upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu, the texlive files have mixed up the configurations and therefore the distribution is not able to find the relevant fonts I have used in my earlier documents.

In this context, I downloaded the ISO file for TexLive from the TexLive website first. I then completely removed the texlive package from my system and the directories storing the TexLive configurations. Finally, I mounted the ISO file and installed TexLive on my system. I set the paths according to the recommendations of the installer and therefore the files are now compiling through the use of the command prompt.

However, I prefer Kile as an IDE for latex. Whenever, I try to install Kile it also asks to download the tex-common, texlive-* packages and their corresponding dependencies.

I therefore downloaded the kile package to a local directory by using

```
apt-get download kile
```

and then attempted to install kile by using

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i kile*
```

After this point, the Synaptic Manager tells me that the kile package is broken and it should be repaired by installing the relevant dependencies. The Software Manager also shows its window. How do I stop this from happening, or is there another better IDE for kile? Do have to really go through the painful way of compiling kile from source?

Comment: Are you sure you just didn't forgot to install some ``texlive-``* packages? Most fonts are in ``-recommended`` and ``-extra`` packages. I have no problem at all using TeXLive 2010 with Kile. It is of strong advice to stick with your package management and not to install it from upstream for reasons like this.

Comment: A small request: Please read the question carefully. I said, I installed the texlive distribution by using the ISO.

Comment: If you want to force installation ignoring dependencies, you should use `--ignore-depends` flag with `dpkg`. Maybe it will work for you, but I still don't understand why didn't you just reinstall texlive with `apt-get`.

Comment: @Indian Yes, that's what I mean. And again: don't do that. Stick with your OS package management to prevent problems you are running into now.

Comment: @Andrey: When I upgraded, the texlive package upgraded too. Unfortunately, something was not correct in the Ubuntu packaging and it was not able to locate the fonts any more. So I had to uninstall everything. I did this uninstalling and installing for about 5 to 6 times, all in vain.

Comment: @Indian: This is _not_ Windows, where you can "fix" problems by repeatedly uninstalling and installing things.

Comment: See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) AFAIK 12.10 has TL2012 natively. Use that.

Comment: @MartinSchröder As I already said in the question, I have installed TexLive from the ISO, and yes I DO KNOW that this is not windows. Apparently therefore, the upgradation process is not able to delete the old configuration files and also the places where the configuration files are "hidden" is not known. As a result, I wouldn't be wrong in saying that the Ubuntu texlive packaging for 12.10 has gone terribly wrong. Furthermore, I am aware of TL being available natively with Ubuntu, I have been using it for the last 4 yrs. Only this time it didn't work to upgrade well!